# Ionic 3: Why are events taking so long to respond?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using Ionic 3, and have published two events that listen for the open/close of the menu. I am trying to toggle the "menu" icon to a "close" icon. Everything is working, however the icon change happens very slowly.

**app.html**

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" (ionOpen)="menuOpened()" (ionClose)="menuClosed()">
    <ion-content>
        ...
```

**app.component.ts**

```
menuOpened() {
    this.events.publish('menu:opened', '');
}

menuClosed() {
    this.events.publish('menu:closed', '');
}
```

On my home page, I am subscribing to the event like this:

**home.ts**

```
visible: boolean = false;

constructor(public events: Events) {
    events.subscribe('menu:opened', () => {
        this.toggleNavButtonIcon();
    });

    events.subscribe('menu:closed', () => {
        this.toggleNavButtonIcon();
    });

    ...
}

...

private toggleNavButtonIcon(): boolean {
    console.log('toggleNavButtonIcon called');
    return this.visible = !this.visible;
}
```

**home.html**

```
<button ion-button menuToggle>
  <ion-icon [name]="visible ? 'close' : 'menu'"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

When I click the menu button, the event is fired immediately. I can also see the logging in the console immediately. The actual icon does not change for a good 2-3 seconds though.

Is there something I can do differently to make the icon toggle as instantaneous as the event is published?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Could you please re-produce your problem at https://stackblitz.com?

Comment: Sure! `https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-mm4qai`. It looks like the methods are working, but the icon isn't reacting at all.

Comment: Seem like Angular ChangeDetector did not work here. Just call it manually. AndrWeisR's answer below is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

// Inject ChangeDetectorRef in your constructor.
public changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef

private toggleNavButtonIcon(): boolean {
    console.log('toggleNavButtonIcon called');

    this.visible = !this.visible;
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges(); // <==========
    return this.visible;
}
```

From the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef), "Checks the change detector and its children".